# Join one table with only 1 first matching record

Tags: sql

```
--------------------Table1-------------
Table1Id            item      SaleId       Dimensions
1                   test1      41           10*11*12
2                   test2      41           13*14*15

--------------------Table2-------------
Table2Id     item         Description   
1           test1         Test element1 desc 1
2           test1         Test element1 desc 2
3           test2         Test element2 desc 1
4           Test2         Test element2 desc 2
```

Currently I am using following query.

```
select Table1.Table1Id, Table1.item, Table1.Dimensions, Table2.Description
on Table1.item = Table2.item
where Table1.SaleId = 41
```

But I want result like that (Need to join Table1.item with first record against item in Table2)

```
Result :
Table1Id            item            Dimensions       Description
1                   test1           10*11*12          Test element1 desc 1
2                   test2           13*14*15          Test element2 desc 1
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: The specified query is invalid since it has no FROM clause.

Comment: What you are describing is a very common problem. Your join returns multiple rows. You have to decide which row you want. You state that you want the "first" row, but you have to decide somehow what defines first. It could be an aggregate like MIN or MAX. Or you could use ROW_NUMBER with an order by.

Comment: Based on Table2.id ascending.

Answer (score 2):

The most typical way for handling this is to use the ANSI-standard `row_number()`:

```
Select t1.Table1Id, t1.item, t1.Dimensions, t2.Description
from table1 t1 join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by t2.item order by t2.table2id desc) as seqnum
      from table2 t2
     ) t
     on t1.item = t2.item and t2.seqnum = 1
where t1.SaleId = 41;
```